# Web API Model Binding with Multipart formdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to be able to get model binding (or whatever) to give out the model from a multipart form data request in **ASP.NET MVC Web API**?

I see various blog posts but either things have changed between the post and actual release or they don't show model binding working.

This is an outdated post: [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

and so is this: [Asynchronous File Upload using ASP.NET Web API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx)

I found this code (and modified a bit) somewhere which reads the values manually:

**Model:**

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public byte[] Stream { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        IEnumerable<HttpContent> parts = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result.Contents;


        string mimeType;
        if (!parts.TryGetFormFieldValue("mimeType", out mimeType))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var media = parts.ToArray()[1].ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

        // create the model here
        var model = new TestModel()
            {
                MimeType = mimeType,
                Stream = media
            };
        // save the model or do something with it
        // repository.Save(model)

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**Test:**

```
[DeploymentItem("test_sound.aac")]
[TestMethod]
public void CanPostMultiPartData()
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent { { new StringContent("audio/aac"),  "mimeType"}, new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("test_sound.aac")) };

    this.controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage {Content = content};
    var response = this.controller.Post();

    Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This code is basically fragile, un-maintainable and further, doesn't enforce the model binding or data annotation constraints.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:** I've seen this [post](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-5.html) and this makes me think - do I have to write a new formatter for every single model that I want to support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mark Jones linked over to my blog post http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/23/web-api-generic-mediatypeformatter-for-file-upload/ which led me here.  I got to thinking about how to do what you want.

I believe if you combine my method along with TryValidateProperty() you should be able accomplish what you need.  My method will get an object deserialized, however it does not handle any validation.  You would need to possibly use reflection to loop through the properties of the object then manually call TryValidateProperty() on each one.  This method it is a little more hands on but I'm not sure how else to do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382181.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/310997/TryValidateProperty-not-work-with-generic-function

Edit: Someone else asked this question and I decided to code it just to make sure it would work.  Here is my updated code from my blog with validation checks.

```
public class FileUpload<T>
{
    private readonly string _RawValue;

    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string MediaType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }

    public List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults = new List<ValidationResult>(); 

    public FileUpload(byte[] buffer, string mediaType, 
                      string fileName, string value)
    {
        Buffer = buffer;
        MediaType = mediaType;
        FileName = fileName.Replace("\"","");
        _RawValue = value;

        Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(_RawValue);

        foreach (PropertyInfo Property in Value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var Results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(Property.GetValue(Value),
                                          new ValidationContext(Value) 
                                          {MemberName = Property.Name}, Results);
            ValidationResults.AddRange(Results);
        }
    }

    public void Save(string path, int userId)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        var SafeFileName = Md5Hash.GetSaltedFileName(userId,FileName);
        var NewPath = Path.Combine(path, SafeFileName);

        if (File.Exists(NewPath))
        {
            File.Delete(NewPath);
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(NewPath, Buffer);

        var Property = Value.GetType().GetProperty("FileName");
        Property.SetValue(Value, SafeFileName, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it try. This makes me wonder, why use multipart form-data approach at all? If I switch to a JSON payload, I don't have to handle any single thing. The byte array can be transmitted as base64 encoded string which is pretty standard. Is multipart buying us anything for all this extra headache?

Answer (score 9):

There is a good example of a generic formatter for file uploads here http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/23/web-api-generic-mediatypeformatter-for-file-upload/. If I was going to have multiple controllers accepting file uploads then this would be the approach I would take.

P.S. Having looked around this seems like a better example for your upload within the controller http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

***Update***

**Re: The usefulness of the Multipart approach**, this is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)  but effectively this boils down to the multipart approach being well build for significantly sized binary payloads etc...

**Is DEFAULT model binding going to work?**

The standard/default model binder for WebApi is not built to cope with the model you have specified i.e. one that mixes simple types and Streams & byte arrays (not so simple)... This is a quote from the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) that inspired the lonetechie's:

> “Simple types” uses model binding. Complex types uses the formatters.
>   A “simple type” includes: primitives, TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid,
>   Decimal, String, or something with a TypeConverter that converts from
>   strings

Your use of a byte array on your model and the need to create that from a stream/content of the request is going to direct you to using formatters instead.

**Send model and files separately?**

Personally I would look to separate the file uploading from the model... perhaps not an option for you... this way you would POST to the same Controller and route when you use a MultiPart data content type this will invoke the file uploading formatter and when you use application/json or x-www-form-urlencoded then it will do simple type model binding... Two POST's may be out of the question for you but it is an option...

**Custom model binder?**

I had some minor success with a [custom model binder](http://forums.asp.net/t/1770906.aspx/1), you can do something with this perhaps... this could be made generic (with some moderate effort) and could be registered globally in the binder provider for reuse...

This may be worth a play?

```
public class Foo
{
    public byte[] Stream { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FoosController : ApiController
{

    public void Post([ModelBinder(typeof(FileModelBinder))] Foo foo)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Custom model binder:

```
public class FileModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public FileModelBinder()
    {

    }

    public bool BindModel(
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext,
        System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var inputModel = new Foo();

            inputModel.Bar = "";  //From the actionContext.Request etc
            inputModel.Stream = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
                                            .Result;

            bindingContext.Model = inputModel;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
             HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't see how I can use model binding or any of the validation that comes with it.

Comment: Apologies - I will try improve my answer shortly but before I do... what other properties to your foresee these models containing, are they solely related to file uploads or will form, entity information be there too?

Comment: Knowing properties beforehand is precisely something I want to avoid. Rather, I would like it to do model binding, so yeah, I would expect it have whatever model binding supports right now. Also, see my comment to @particleman. I'm wondering the usefulness of multipart approach over JSON payload.

Comment: The usefulness of the Multipart approach - well, it seems a JSON payload is so trivial and so so simpler - its a no brainer! Then why the heck this multipart madness? Even for larger files, what does it change? The same amount of bytes are going over the wire anyway.   Your custom model binder seems interesting but right now, I'm sticking to JSON payloads simply for its simplicity (and the fact that I don't need to write a single line of code to do the plumbing).