# ASP.Net WebAPI MediaTypeMapping using Body Content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible (or sensible) to build a custom `MediaTypeMapping` to select a `MediaTypeFormatter` based on content from the Request Body?

I'm thinking specifically of a case where I have a very non-descriptive text/plain in a multipart/form-data payload and I want to use heuristics to work out what's contained.

I'm currently doing this in a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` that looks at the first few lines, and if the content begins with `{` then it assumes JSON, if it's `word,word,word` the the commas indicate CSV.

I was thinking that a `MediaTypeMapping` would be cleaner but I don't know if it's sensible to try and match from the Body content.

Comment: Another useful case for this would be a MultipartMediaTypeFormatter that could process an upload and then look for existing formatters to bind the various parts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697310/web-api-model-binder-doesnt-work-with-httppostedfilebase and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593001/web-api-model-binding-with-multipart-formdata/12603828#12603828

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way you can really Inspect content in Webapi. You can not read the stream more than once.

Comment: I don't want to read the stream more than once...I just want to peek ahead :) In any case, I'm not sure how much I can do with a single multipart/form-data payload reader because I can't return more than one type in any case. Nor can I bind more than one complex class (read from the body) to an Action. It's a shame there's no multipart form reader out of the box that binds multiple complex model types.

Comment: Well the i think you should Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) when you are done with the Stream . Tell me if this works out.